# Microsoft Access Text Driver - Syntax errors received if spaces are present in CSV source paths

Tags: sql, excel, vba, csv, text-driver

I am using **Microsoft Access Text Driver** in a `SELECT` Query to **JOIN 2 CSV files** located at **different paths**.

There is a space in one of subfolders called "**TEST FOLDER**" of a csv's source path. If  I rename it to "**TESTFOLDER**" and update my csv path in code, the query runs properly. But if i keep that space, it results in

> Microsoft Access Text Driver Syntax error in FROM Clause

These could be different network folders, by the way.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim oCon As New ADODB.Connection, oRs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSql$, strCon$, strF1$, strF2$

strF1 = "C:\Users\ADAM\Documents\TEST FOLDER\Names.csv"
strF2 = "C:\Users\ADAM\Downloads\Address.csv"

strCon = "Driver=Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv);Dbq=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & ";Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;"

strSql = "Select n.*, a.[Address] " & _
            "From " & strF1 & " n " & _
            "INNER JOIN " & strF2 & " a " & _
            "ON n.Name = a.Name "

    oCon.Open strCon
    Set oRs = oCon.Execute(strSql)

'    Sheet1.UsedRange.EntireRow.Delete
'    Sheet1.Cells(1).CopyFromRecordset oRs

    On Error Resume Next
    Sheet1.ListObjects(1).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

    Dim oQT As QueryTable
    Set oQT = Sheet1.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcQuery, oRs, Destination:=Sheet1.Cells(1, 1)).QueryTable
    With oQT
        .Refresh
    End With
End Sub
```

I have tried enclosing the csv paths in [square-brackets], 'single-quotes', "double-quotes", `back-ticks` etc., but I still get the Syntax error in FROM Clause.

I would appreciate some help resolving this issue.

Comment: `"From " & strF1 & "...` --> `"From '" & strF1 & "'...` Same for `strF2`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie i had already tried that...if i add single-quotes, it gives me another error `[Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver]<filepath> is not a valid name. Make sure it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.`

Comment: Hmmm. I see you use a full path to a file as a table name. But a file is not a table. Maybe take a look at https://superuser.com/questions/420997/is-there-a-way-to-do-an-inner-join-in-excel-between-2-csv-files

Comment: Yes, that is the syntax i found and it works properly if there are no spaces in the filepaths. BTW there is no documentation or bug i could search that would indicate `Microsoft Access Text Driver` has an issue with spaces in filepaths.